# SMB Client Issue - NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Tags: linux

I was facing an issue while connecting to Windows host from Linux host to fetch shared files.
These commands were not working

```
$/usr/bin/smbclient -L windowsHost
$/usr/bin/smbclient \\\\windowsHost\\test
```

Where windowsHost is the host where files are shared.

The error i get is

```
Enter *user*'s password:
session setup failed: **NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE**
```

Comment: while ++ for solving your own problem, this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, its the smbclient command i was using.

$/usr/bin/smbclient \\windowsHost\test -U domain\usr pwd

Output:

Domain=[*domain*]OS=[Windows Server 2008...]

As the NT user account having windows host/dir access is with the domain abd hence i needed to use it with smbclient.